cmake export static lib and hide 3rd party libs
I am creating a static library lets call it X. This library uses rapidjson library in .cpp files. When I export this as static library, I want to hide rapidjson dependency. Another project should be able to link with
target_link_librares(another_project PUBLIC X)

My CMake configuration:
add_library(X STATIC
    hub.cpp
)

target_include_directories(X PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

get_target_property(X_INCLUDE_DIRS X INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

target_link_libraries(X
    PUBLIC
    Y // this can be visible
    PRIVATE
    rapidjson // this should not required when another project links to X
)

install(TARGETS X
    EXPORT X-targets
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
)

install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/
    DESTINATION include/X
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h" 
)

install(EXPORT X-targets
    FILE X-config.cmake
    NAMESPACE X::
    DESTINATION lib/X
)

When I install this and link to X, it requires for the line. However, this rapidjson
is only used in the C++ files. And I want to hide this from end user.
find_package(RapidJson REQUIRED)

Is it possible to statically bundle these RapidJSON functions inside the X static library?

That's not possible with static libraries. A static library really is just an archive of all object files for the library. When you link with a static library, it's no different from linking with the object files themselves. Hopefully this makes it easier to see why you can't "hide" the dependencies for the static library, as the target application must link with those dependencies as well.

@Someprogrammerdude "not possible" is a bit strong, you can combine multiple static libraries into a single one (they are just basically zip files after all), it's also possible to put the dependency on the static library into the cmake config file for the library
